# How i can build start button to load counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a counter and I want it to start only when I press button start (not on page load). How I can do that?

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },

    {

      duration: 6000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
      }

    });



});
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline;
}

.startbtn {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="startbtn">Start</div>

<div class="counter" data-count="378">0</div> km
<div class="counter" data-count="147">0</div> km
<div class="counter" data-count="60">0</div> minut
```

Comment: Wrap in `$(".startbtn").on("click",function() { $('.counter').each(function() { .....)}; )};`

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `click` event to your element `startbtn`.

## Look at this code snippet

Click on start.

```js
var start = function() {
  $('.counter').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

    $({
      countNum: $this.text()
    }).animate({
        countNum: countTo
      }, {
        duration: 6000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
          $this.text(this.countNum);
          //alert('finished');
        }
      });
  });
};

$('#startbtn').click(start);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline;
}

.startbtn {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="startbtn" id='startbtn'>Start</div>

<div class="counter" data-count="378">0</div> km
<div class="counter" data-count="147">0</div> km
<div class="counter" data-count="60">0</div> minut
```

See? the counter wasn't executed until you clicked on element `start`.

Comment: But is it worth answering at all? It is REALLY basic jQuery - and perhaps wait with the ES6 syntax

Comment: @mplungjan some people have difficulties to resolve problems.  So, it's important to give them some help.  On the other hand, I'm going to edit the answer and remove  "ES6 syntax".

Comment: I already commented the solution to the question- reload and see it under the question. Hence it is no longer needed in my opinion. Anyone spending another 10 minutes on any tutorial or just browsing "jquery click" would be able to get the solution to this. I really like to help people but no effort irritates me

Comment: @mplungjan perfect, I respect your position.   The answer helps to the OP with an executable solution.